# How to Pass customfields in c# whmcs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, base64, whmcs

I want to add the customfields in add order api. How to create an array like that: "an array of base64 encoded serialized array of product custom field values"

https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/addorder/

I have tried with

```c#
Dictionary<string, string> customfiled = new Dictionary<string, string>();

customfiled.Add("1", "Hello");

var tt2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customfiled);
  
string str =Base64Encode(tt2);
```

Comment: I think you need to declare it as `string[]` since customfields is an array string type not a dictionary

Answer (score 2):

I have created a class that will hold the list of key/values serialized as JSON.

Here is the class:

```
class ArrayOfBase64Array
{
    // serialized JSON 
    private List<string> list = new List<string>();
        
    public void Add(NameValueCollection collection) 
    {
        foreach(var key in collection.AllKeys)
        {
           this.Add(key, collection[key]);
        }
    }

    public void Add<T>(string key, T value) {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string,T>();
        dict.Add(key, value);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
        list.Add(Base64Encode(json));
    }
    
    public string[] ToArray() 
    {
        return list.ToArray();
    }
    
    string Base64Encode(string value) 
    {
      return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value));
    }
}
```

The AddOrder payload expects a shape that matches this C# class:

```
// lots of fields omitted for brevity
class AddOrder
{
    public string   action {get;set;}      
    public string[] domain {get;set;}  
    public string[] customfields {get;set;}
}
```

To create an AddOrder instance with customfields you can now do this:

```
   // create an AddOrder instance
   var addOrder = new AddOrder 
   { 
      action = "AddOrder",
      domain = new [] {"one.example.com", "two.example.com"} 
   };
   
   // build our customfields collection
   var cfarray = new ArrayOfBase64Array();
   cfarray.Add("1", "FuBar");
   cfarray.Add("2", 999);
   cfarray.Add("3", true);
   cfarray.Add("4", new JObject(new JProperty("Foo", 4711.42)));
   
   // or if you have a namevaluecollection
   var nvc = new NameValueCollection { {"5", "test namevalue 1"}, {"6", "another value"} };
   cfarray.Add(nvc);

   // store the customfields as an array of strings
   addOrder.customfields = cfarray.ToArray();
```

This is what the data looks like when POST-ed to the server:

```
  { "action":"AddOrder",
    "domain":["one.example.com","two.example.com"],
    "customfields":[
       "eyIxIjoiRnVCYXIifQ==",
       "eyIyIjo5OTl9",
       "eyIzIjp0cnVlfQ==",
       "eyI0Ijp7IkZvbyI6NDcxMS40Mn19",   
       "eyI1IjoidGVzdCBuYW1ldmFsdWUgMSJ9",
       "eyI2IjoiYW5vdGhlciB2YWx1ZSJ9"]
  }
```

And this is what is in each of the encoded base64 strings:

```
{"1":"FuBar"}
{"2":999}
{"3":true}
{"4":{"Foo":4711.42}}
{"5":"test namevalue 1"}
{"6":"another value"}
```

Comment: how to pass this request to api  I am using nameValueCollection it is not accepting the array of customfields.

Comment: @MuhammadArsalan your final customfields can't be a NameValueCollection. It has to be a string[] (or List<string> ) if you want it to match what the API expects. I did add an extra overload to show you can provide a NameValueCollection that will then be handled appropriately for the AddOrder payload.

Comment: can you share complete addorder Code please

Comment: @MuhammadArsalan the documentation you linked allows you easily to extend AddOrder and add the missing properties and their type mapping. I'm not willing to spend time on copy/pasting stuff you can do yourself. Copy the Parameter and Type column, paste it in the class, on each line move the Type in front of the parametername, add `public` in front of that and add `{get;set;}`. So you end up with `public int clientid {get;set;}`, rinse/repeat for every row. Change a `float[]` in `decimal[]`. Done.